# How to/Should I install python 3.5 from 2.7? (windows)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5

I use python 2.7 and have the following packages installed:

```
distribute
decorator
*matplotlib
memory-profiler
networkx
*numpy
Pillow
pip
py2exe
PyAudio
*PyBluez
*pygame
pyglet
*PyInstaller
pyparsing
*pyserial
python-dateutil
pytz
pywin32
requests
scikit-learn
*scipy
setuptools
six
```

The ones marked with a * are critical.

I want to move to python 3.5, abandoning 2.7 completely (don't want to have both).

1. Can I do that while still keeping my old packages or do I have to install everything from scratch?
2. Are there any reasons I shouldn't move to py 3.5 from 2.7?
3. Should I move first to 3.3/3.4 or just straight to 3.5?
4. I'm not using a virtualenv because I'm not very familiar with that. Should I?

UPDATE: Follow-up.

I can just make a list of the packages I have and then manually install all of them.

5. How do I go about installing 3.5 and uninstalling 2.7?

Do I remove 2.7 first then install 3.5 or have them both simultaneously (will this create any issue?) then remove 2.7?

I mainly use python for numpy, bluetooth, serial, OpenCV, OpenGL. I intend to foray into a bit of web too later. I don't have any issue with syntax or method change. I was previously holding out for pyinstaller but that too has been recently ported to 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized after switching.

Don't install python 3.5 if you want OpenCV to work. It's not yet built for that and some functions don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reinstall all your packages.  You should check that all those packages are available for Python 3.  (From your question it sounds like you may have already done this, but not totally sure.)

It would be wise to test how things go with Python 3 before completely abandoning Python 2.  You can do this by installing the two side-by-side, or by installing Python 3 in a virtual machine or some such thing.  If you have existing code you want to keep using, you definitely want to test it to make sure everything runs smoothly on Python 3.

There is likely no reason to go to 3.3/3.4.  Just go straight to 3.5.

Virtualenv can definitely be useful for setting up different Python environments on the same computer.  However, you'll still need to install Python 3 before you can use it in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Moving packages is bad idea, it is safier to reinstall them using pip:

- Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. It will store all packages and versions in file
- Install Python 3.5
- Run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It will install same packages on your python3.5
- Run all tests against this Python to make sure your app still works as expected

The only reason to stay with 2.7 is incompatible code: if your code or one of your packages does not work on Py3K.

Virtualenv is useful tool, any python developer should know how to use it.

Comment: this is a good example of why you should use virtualenv or conda.  You only have to create a new environment with a different version of python and you're good to go.

Comment: what should I prefer over virtualenv or conda?